# About DevExpress UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I've created one usercontrol in vs2010 professional . The usercontrol is from DevExpress.
I've used usercontrol's load() event. And i used xml file for my usercontrol application. In usercontrol i've added DevExpress xtraTreeList control & i populated nodes of xtraTreeList  by using my xml file. My xml file is present in my applications directory path means- E:\MsgBlasterApplicationtemp\MsgBlasterApplication\bin\Debug\Database . 
When i'm drag & drop my usercontrol in my form then it gives me error. The error is as follows--

`Failed to creste component ' TreeListUserControl'. The error message follows:
'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException:Could not find part of path.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior and you will reproduce it if you use the standard GridView on the standard UserControl.  When the UserControl is positioned on a form, all controls on it work as if the application runs :(.  Here is the solution which should work fine for you:

```
    private void XtraUserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(!DesignMode) {
            // your code to populate the treeList with data
         }
    }
```